# Route Me map not showing in iphone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, maps

Well in our project we can't see the tiles of the map.

Other things like dragging, zooming, tapping the Map, plotting pin points as well as their delegate methods work fine in project.

And in this project we don't have any run-time errors...

Our Console Output :

> [15624:207] Opening database at ../iPhone
>   Simulator/4.2/Applications/1DE289F1-F71F/Documents/MapOpenStreetMap.sqlite
>
> [15624:207] Map contents initialised. view: MapView at 0,0-320,400
>   tileSource RMCachedTileSource: 0x4c88730> renderer
>   RMCoreAnimationRenderer: 0x4c56f50>

Please guide us.

Thanks & Regards,

Zahur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant see the tiles means. Tell me more. But when dealing with Route-Me problems go to the issues list in google code. It helped me solve many issues in route me.

http://code.google.com/p/route-me/issues/list

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, well I had already posted there, you can too refer issue #159. I had also posted the output screen at the issue. Tiles; I mean the images of the map.

Comment: Have you included any extra code with the MapView project. Becoz if you include routeme in your project as said in the documentation it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use these commands in viewdidload
[RMMapView class];
mapView.contents.tileSource = [[RMOpenStreetMapSource alloc] init];

Answer (score 0):

Guess what it working now.....

But now it shows nine warnings related to the mapView & proj projects. I had already done with deleting the previous builds of mapView, proj &  ActualApplication. But same result.

Warnings:

ld: warning: directory '/Users/.…./projects/MapView/build/Debug-iphoneos' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/.…./projects/MapView/build/Debug-iphonesimulator' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/.…./projects/MapView/build/MapView.build/Debug-iphoneos/MapView.build/Objects-normal/armv6' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/.…./projects/MapView/build/MapView.build/Debug-iphoneos/MapView.build/Objects-normal/armv7' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/.…./projects/Proj4/build/Debug-iphoneos' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/.…./projects/Proj4/build/Debug-iphonesimulator' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/.…./projects/Proj4/build/Proj4.build/Debug-iphoneos/Proj4.build/Objects-normal/armv6' following -L not found

ld: warning: directory '/Users/.…./projects/Proj4/build/Proj4.build/Debug-iphoneos/Proj4.build/Objects-normal/armv7' following -L not found

Regards Zahur

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like issue I experienced before.
To solve it just send all messages in main thread.
Like instead of:

```
[mapView moveToLatLong:coordinate];
```

create and use function:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(moveMapTo) withObject:nil];

/// Call this function in main thread to ensure correct map reaction    
-(void)moveMapTo{
        [_mapView moveToLatLong:coordinate];
    }
```

It should resolve your problem.